# Prestashop 1.7-> How can i add new ajax areas in cart page?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add new Ajax areas in cart page. see the image below. i want to put an input that will refresh when i increment the quantity of a product and show the number of the product inside the cart.

[image: Shopping cart example]
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you have to use the Prestashop hooks.

You can add data to the hooks using modules.

**Available hooks on the shopping-cart page**

- displayCrossSellingShoppingCart
- displayShoppingCart
- displayShoppingCartFooter

You can find all available hooks here: [Prestashop 1.7 - List of module hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/)

You can find more information on how to use hooks here [Prestashop 1.7 - Usage of hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/)